# Reporting Solution web-based using .net framework suggestions

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting, business-intelligence

I have a situation, where we have a MS SQL Server 2012 database and the client is requesting a number of reports to be generated from this db.  The client is also requesting that this data should be seen in his current portal (custom web based using .Net C# and ASP.NET) or a hosted web-application in his IIS.

I was thinking of going for something which lets you create queries on the fly with the least amount of effort and with the possibility to customize them through code (since the requirements always get changed + certain reports are very easy to make).  Just to give you an example of what I had in mind is Ubiq (see video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgXrbdnsa9Y )

Kindly can you please give me some examples or solutions that can be used.

Comment: Just to warn you, SO rules state that questions should not ask for software or tool recommendations because they tend to generate opinion-based replies - you might want to adjust this question to suit. That aside, it sounds like what you're asking for is a BI tool of some kind - SQL Server has these (look at SSAS cubes or Tabular) and you could look at those for a starter. However, defined reports and BI are two different things, so think carefully about whether a BI solution fits the client's requirements here - they would need to learn how to use any BI tool you chose.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of reporting solutions out there, i recommend you to try them all and pick the one that better fits your needs, with that in mind, you can start by trying [DBxtra](http://dbxtra.com/), which lets you create queries easily (although not on the fly) and lets you customize them if you need/want to, it also runs on the .NET Framework, so you can easily host it along with your customer's application.

P.S.: I'm a DBxtra evangelist.